# Let $f$ be a function. Does it hold in general that $f(A) = B$ implies that $A = f^{-1}(B)$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I know that when calculating the pre-image of a function $f:X \rightarrow Y$ in a given subset $B$, that is, $f^{-1}(B)=\{x \in X\mid f(x) \in B\}$,the $f^{-1}$ simbol is just notation because it does not imply the existance of the inverse of the function.

But, taking into account this, can we conclude that $f(A)=B \implies A=f^{-1}(B)$ is not necessarily true if $f$ is not invertible and the reciprocal is also not true? Because I have been trying to find a counterexample but I haven't been able to. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! I think there is a typo. Maybe you meant $f^{-1}(B) = \{x\in X | f(x)\in B\}$.

Comment: Yes, sure. My fault!

Answer (score 2):

The proposed relation does not hold in general.

In order to conclude so, consider the function $f := \{(0,1),(1,1)\}$ as well as the sets $A = \{0\}$ and $B = \{1\}$. On the one hand, we have that $f(A) = B$. On the other hand, $f^{-1}(B) = \{0,1\}$, which is different from $A$. Therefore the proposed claim is false.

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed false. It's true when $f(x)\in B$ implies $x\in A$ - equivalently, $f(X\setminus A)\subseteq Y\setminus B$. This is true, for example, if $f$ is injective. But consider $X=\Bbb R,Y=\Bbb R$ and $f(x)=x^2$.

$f([0,\infty))=[0,\infty)$ but $f^{-1}([0,\infty))=\Bbb R$, so we do not have $f(A)=B\implies A=f^{-1}(B)$.

$f$ doesn't *need* to be injective for this to be true, either. Consider again $X=Y=\Bbb R$ and:

$$f:x\mapsto\begin{cases}x^2&|x|\le1\\x&|x|>1\end{cases}$$

If $A=[-1,1]$ then $f(A)=B=[0,1]$, and $f^{-1}(B)=[-1,1]=A$ despite the fact $f$ does not inject.

Answer (score 1):

**Theorem.** Let $f\colon X\to Y$ be a function. Then $f$ is one-to-one if and only if for every $A\subseteq X$, if $f(A)=B$ then $f^{-1}(B)=A$.

*Proof.* Suppose first that $f$ is one-to-one, and let $f(A)=B$. To prove $f^{-1}(B)=A$ we prove they each contain each other.

If $a\in A$, then $f(a)\in B$, and therefore, since $f^{-1}(B)=\{x\in X\mid f(x)\in B\}$, we have that $a\in f^{-1}(B)$. Thus, $A\subseteq f^{-1}(B) = f^{-1}(f(A))$.  (This holds without any assumptions on $f$ beyond it being a function).

Now let $x\in f^{-1}(B)$. Then $f(x)\in B=f(A)=\{f(a)\mid a\in A\}$, so there exists $a\in A$ such that $f(x)=f(a)$. **Because $f$ is assumed to be one-to-one**, we conclude that $x=a$, so $x\in A$. Thus, $f^{-1}(B)\subseteq A$, and we have equality.

Conversely, assume that for all $A\subseteq X$, if $B=f(A)$ then $A=f^{-1}(B)$. Let $x,x'\in X$ be such that $f(x)=f(x')$, and let $A=\{x\}$. Then $f(x')\in f(A) = \{f(x)\}=\{f(x')\}$, so therefore $x'\in f^{-1}(f(A))=A=\{x\}$. Therefore, $x'=x$, so we conclude that $f$ is one-to-one. $\Box$